Hibernate 5.6 has huge performance issues after upgrade of Java, Spring &Hibernate versions. Why?
Upgraded a java project which was on Java 8 + spring 4.0 + hibernate 3.3 to java 11 + spring 5.3 + hibernate 5.6 . After the upgrade the hibernate select queries become very slow. When there're many results for a select query then the hibernate 5.6 is taking a lot of time compared to hibernate 3.3. What could be the reason?

You should inspect your mapping, especially if you come from hbm XML file to JPA annotation. And it is rather strange to migrate to Spring 5 / Hibernate 5 with Java 11 while there Spring 6 / Hibernate 6 with  Java 17, each being LTS.

It's a legacy project and when we started migration a couple of years ago, those were the org approved versions. it's mix of both very few hbm files and more annotations.

https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/ Hypersistence Optimizer checks your JPA and Hibernate data access layer and provides you tips about how you can optimize it. With this tool, you can book vlad's in-depth jpa and hibernate knowledge as a service.

You should check in your Hibernate 3.3 logs if there are some kind of information about the mapping being done and compare with equivalent in Hibernate 5.6. Another alternative is, if you know some methods that are slower, check if you don't have eager or more select than wanted : since your Java 8 stack is not that old, you could try using https://github.com/quick-perf/quickperf and compare test with 3.3 / 5.6.

It wasn't an issue with this upgrade. It's related to a different configuration issue from jetty server. It's resolved. Thanks.
